Error in trayectory generation Staubli VAL 3
I have the following code in VAL 3:
          pose_xyz_aux=here(tTool1,world)
          pose_xyz_aux.trsf.z=pose_xyz_aux.trsf.z+50
          movej(pose_xyz_aux,tTool1,mNomSpeed)
          waitEndMove() 

When I execute it, I have an error in trajectory generator. If I move manually to point pose_xyz_aux, I do not have any problem to reach it. So I do not understand why the robot cannot make the path.  Why is this?

You use the point type variable as the first parameter in movej, not the joint type. It is possible to use this type of parameter with movej, but this involves the robot performing inverse kinematics to convert Cartesian pose into joint angles. Suppose the start, end, or some intermediate pose happens to be in singularity. In that case, this may fail, even if the movement can be done with the robot control pendant by setting joint angles manually.

i am trying to move the robot +10cm in Z directon (base) with that command. Actual pose is a point that gives me the camera in xy,z;rx,ry,rz So, if I can not do it with cartesian points, Do I have to calculate the Ik from pose_xyz_aux and move it using Joint point? Couldnt I do with cartesian points?
